# How to make that sql view to show data differences

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

Recently i am preparing Edit history for my database. I made a table, that saves record before and after update. I added column to history table that pairs 2 records (that one before and after update). So i have fully history table.

What i want to do now is to create complicated(in my opinion) view. I want to show all the differences that are between all records from that table. Let me explain.

I have got 20 columns in that table, but let's take 4 to show what do i mean:
Title/Author/Date/PairIndex. Those are column names.

And the data:

```
Book1/Author1/30-03-1990/1
Book1/Author1/30-04-1990/1
Book2/Author2/30-03-2004/2
Book3/Author3/30-03-2004/2
```

here i got 2 updates. First update was only date change. Second update changed both Book title and Author. I want to show in my view something like:

```
1-- 30-03-1990 -- 30-04-1990
2-- Book2 -- Book3
2-- Author2 -- Author3
```

So every difference has its own row with data that differs. And that made for each pair of records with same PairIndex.

Here is my not working code:

```
Create table Boom ( Book   VARCHAR(10),
                             author VARCHAR(10),
                             date     DATE,
                             id     INT )

INSERT INTO Boom
VALUES ( 'Book1', 'Author1', '19900330', 1 ),
       ( 'Book1', 'Author1', '19900430', 1 ),
       ( 'Book2', 'Author2', '20040330', 2 ),
       ( 'Book3', 'Author3', '20040330', 2 );

WITH cte
AS (
      SELECT Boom.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by author) as RN
      FROM Boom
   ) 

select b1.id, b2.id, b1.date, b2.date
  from cte b1 
  join cte b2 
    on b1.id = b2.id 
   and b1.rn < b2.rn 
   and b1.date <> b2.date

select b1.id, b2.id, b1.author, b2.author
  from cte b1 
  join cte b2 
    on b1.id = b2.id 
   and b1.rn < b2.rn 
   and b1.author<> b2.author
```

Comment: How can you be sure there won't be more than one update?

Comment: There can be more = ) But it will have different ID.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
DECLARE @SomeData AS TABLE ( Book   VARCHAR(10),
                             Author VARCHAR(10),
                             Dt     DATE,
                             ID     INT )

INSERT INTO @SomeData
VALUES ( 'Book1', 'Author1', '19900330', 1 ),
       ( 'Book1', 'Author1', '19900430', 1 ),
       ( 'Book2', 'Author2', '20040330', 2 ),
       ( 'Book3', 'Author3', '20040330', 2 );
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by Book, Author, Dt) as RN
    FROM @SomeData
   )

SELECT a.ID
      ,a.Book
      ,a.Author
      ,a.Dt
      ,b.Book
      ,b.Author
      ,b.Dt
FROM cte AS a LEFT JOIN cte AS b ON a.id = b.id
                                AND a.RN < b.RN
WHERE a.RN = 1
```

Comment: That's good one, but i still need take only differences, not all rows.

Answer (score 1):

Need row_number and then look for the differences

```
WITH cte
AS (
      SELECT table.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by author) as RN
      FROM Table
   ) 

select b1.id, b2.id, b1.date, b2.date
  from cte b1 
  join cte b2 
    on b1.id = b2.id 
   and b1.rn < b2.rn 
   and b1.date <> b2.date;

WITH cte
    AS (
          SELECT table.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by author) as RN
          FROM Table
       ) 

select b1.id, b2.id, b1.author, b2.author
  from cte b1 
  join cte b2 
    on b1.id = b2.id 
   and b1.rn < b2.rn 
   and b1.author<> b2.author;
```

Comment: It seems it lacks some data. What is cte?

Comment: Show some effort.  Did you try this with the actual name of your table?  CTE Common Table Expression.

Comment: ofc i did. I am getting error with that cte, that's why i asked. 
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid object name 'cte'.

Comment: Please post your exact code that is throwing an error

Comment: I created table and after that tried to execute your code as Query. I mean i place my table name where u got Table (twice).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69760/discussion-between-jan-walczak-and-blam).

Comment: Edited my first post.

Comment: CTE does not span statements.  You need it twice.

Comment: Ok, it works well. Is it possible to do a VIEW from it?